# Binding to checked value in dom-repeat

Tags: data-binding, polymer

I'm trying to bind the checked value of an paper-toggle-button within a dom-repeat.

```
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[settings]]">
        <div item>
            <paper-toggle-button checked="{{item.value}}" on-click="_updateSettings">[[item.name]]</paper-toggle-button>
            [[item.value]]
        </div>
    </template>

    [[settings.0.value]]
```

.

```
properties: {
    settings: {
        type: Array,
        value: [
            {name:"test", value: true}
        ]
    }
}
```

The checked value is set correctly when the component loads but the checked state is only reflected within the loop [[item.value]] not outside [[settings.0.value]]
How can I have the change reflected back to the original property?

Comment: Can you please post the code for the method _updateSettings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a 1-way binding for `items` here:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[settings]]">
```

Try changing this to use a 2-way binding:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{settings}}">
```

Comment: well spotted :) [[settings.0.value]] doesn't update but I can see the rest of the code working now. Thank you.